# Laravel 5: Ajax Post 500 (Internal Server Error) Error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

### I'm trying to submit data via ajax (add to cart) but got an error in console  POST http://localhost/glutax9gs/cartupdate 500 (Internal Server Error)

What's wrong with my code? Is it the javascript or the controller?

---

here is my Route:

```php
Route::get('/cartupdate', 'FrontEndController@cartupdate')->name('update.cart');
Route::post('/cartupdate', 'FrontEndController@cartupdate')->name('cart.update');
```

Controller code is here:

```php
    public function cartupdate(Request $request)
    {

        if ($request->isMethod('post')){

            if (empty(Session::get('uniqueid'))){

                $cart = new Cart;
                $cart->fill($request->all());
                Session::put('uniqueid', $request->uniqueid);
                $cart->save();

            }else{

                $cart = Cart::where('uniqueid',$request->uniqueid)
                    ->where('product',$request->product)->first();
                //$carts = Cart::where('uniqueid',$request->uniqueid)
                        //->where('product',$request->product)->count();
                if (count($cart) > 0 ){
                    $data =  $request->all();
                    $cart->update($data);
                }else{
                    $cart = new Cart;
                    $cart->fill($request->all());
                    $cart->save();
                }

            }
            return response()->json(['response' => 'Successfully Added to Cart.','product' => $request->product]);
        }

        $getcart = Cart::where('uniqueid',Session::get('uniqueid'))->get();

        return response()->json(['response' => $getcart]);
    }
```

jQuery code is here:

```
    $(".to-cart").click(function(){

        var formData = $(this).parents('form:first').serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{{route("cart.update")}}',
            data:formData,
            success: function (data) {
                getCart();
                $.notify(data.response, "success");
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error:', data);
            }
        });
    });
```

View code is here:

```php
        <form>
            <p>
                {{csrf_field()}}
                @if(Session::has('uniqueid'))
                    <input type="hidden" name="uniqueid" value="{{Session::get('uniqueid')}}">
                @else
                    <input type="hidden" name="uniqueid" value="{{str_random(7)}}">
                @endif
      <input type="hidden" name="title" value="{{$product->title}}">
      <input type="hidden" name="product" value="{{$product->id}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="cost" name="cost" value="{{$product->price}}">
      <input type="hidden" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1">
           @if($product->stock != 0 || $product->stock === null )
    <button type="button" class="button style-10 to-cart">Add to cart</button>
              @else
           <button type="button" class="button style-10 to-cart" disabled>Out Of Stock</button>
           @endif
            {{--<button type="button" class="button style-10 hidden-sm to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to cart</button>--}}
            </p>
        </form>
```

Comment: Nothing useful in your laravel log?

Comment: Check your log in `storage/logs`, or check the server error log. A 500 error is a very generic error and does not explain what is going wrong.

Comment: I got this error in Laravel.log
#50 D:\xampp\htdocs\glutax9gs\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 D:\xampp\htdocs\glutax9gs\index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#52 {main}

Comment: That's only a very small part of the stack trace. You're looking for the exact error.

Comment: The way you are creating `Cart` objects breaks the DI and the MVC pattern. It's better to delegate this work to a different class (not the controller), and use something like `Cart::firstOrCreate`, or `Cart::create` depending on the case.

Comment: ErrorException: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in D:\xampp\htdocs\glutax9gs\project\app\Http\Controllers\FrontEndController.php:101

Comment: `$cart` is not an array or a Collection. Since you're using `first()`, it's either going to be a single object or it's going to be null.

Comment: the problem was in $cart variable returned null and I used it in count() > 0 function i just remove count() > 0  and problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, looks like you are using `count()` on a non-array element, that's prohibited. You should modify your check:

From:

```php
if (count($cart) > 0 ){
```

To:

```php
if (is_array($cart) && count($cart) > 0 ){
```

Tip: Verify first that `$cart` is an array before checking its length.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in $cart variable returned null
i just changed from

```php
if (count($cart) > 0 ){
                    $data =  $request->all();
                    $cart->update($data);
                }
```

to this:

```php
if ($cart){
                    $data =  $request->all();
                    $cart->update($data);
                }
```

and problem solve
Thanks to all :)